# R - Drawing a baseball strike zone on a graph with ggplot errors

Tags: r, ggplot2

below is my current code

```
target <- c("BallCalled", "StrikeCalled","StrikeSwinging")
TMData <- Trackman %>% filter(PitchCall %in% target)


plateframe <- 17+2*(9/pi) 
strikezone <- ggplot(NULL, aes(x = px, y = pz)) +
  geom_rect(xmin = -(plateframe/2)/12,
            xmax = (plateframe/2)/12,
            ymin = 1.5, 
            ymax = 3.6, 
            color = "black") +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_x_continuous("Horizontal Plate Location (ft.)", 
                     limits = c(-2,2) +
  scale_y_continuous("Vertical Plate Location (ft.)",
                     limits = c(0,5))

strikezone %+% sample_n(TMData, 264) +
  aes(color = PitchCall) +
  geom_point()
```

I'm hitting nonstop errors. Currently, here is my graph

[current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXAqF.jpg)

This is for baseball data. I have drawn a strike zone per a textbook's instructions. Then, I plotted location on top of it. Here is some sample code, it is vertical and horizontal location

[sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UqfM.png)

Currently, it won't plot for all 256 lines of this data in my code. If  I don't include the box drawing, it does plot fine. But, I need the box. Please help

[What I want is this, but with the box of the strike zone on top of it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUcyD.png)

That's just a ggplot(TMData, aes(x = px, y = pa) plot with a geom_point. I don't know why I can't overlay the two.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing a parentheses to close out your scale_x_continuous function. It should run once that's fixed