# Draw a shape outline outside a graph's points

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have this graph here and I want to add an outline, similar to the one in black, but that is just outside of yellow portion that goes directly around.

[image: Graph]

I tried stat_ellipse, but it was far too big, here's the code for the graph

```
ggplot() + stat_summary_2d(aes(x = plate_x, y = plate_z, z = xCS)) + 
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", 
                       limits = c(10,90), oob = scales::squish, name = "xCS%") +
  xlim(-1.5,1.5) + ylim(0,4.5) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = -0.83, xmax = 0.83, ymin = 1.5, ymax = 3.5), 
            alpha = 0, size = 1, color = "black") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = -0.708, y = 0.15, xend = 0.708, yend = 0.15), 
               size = 1, color = "black") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = -0.708, y = 0.3, xend = -0.708, yend = 0.15), 
               size = 1, color = "black") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = -0.708, y = 0.3, xend = 0, yend = 0.5), size = 1, 
               color = "black") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0.5, xend = 0.708, yend = 0.3), size = 1, 
               color = "black") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.708, y = 0.3, xend = 0.708, yend = 0.15), size = 1, 
               color = "black") + 
  theme_bw() + labs(x = "Plate Side (in)",
                    y = "Plate Height (in)",
                    title = "Probability of a Called Strike") + facet_grid(~stand)
```

where plate x is the side corrdinate, plate z is the height coordinate and xCS is a numeric vector from 0-100. What's shown is only over 50.

Comment: Would your Plate measures be in (ft)? I guess I would say, wouldn't it be misleading to encircle all data with the black line, as graphically you lose the fact of the home plate. It's striking, so to say, the tendency to call strike on a low, inside brush off throw at a left hand batter. Get that ump his glasses!

Comment: Yeah ft, whoops. Well the ideal would be to have both to show the difference.

Comment: There seems a fair bit of interest, lmgtfy - with thanks to Carl Witthoft, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68787914/r-drawing-a-baseball-strike-zone-on-a-graph-with-ggplot-errors), [2](https://blogs.bgsu.edu/statgraphicsalbert/2013/04/13/ggplot2-to-graph-pitching-data/), [3](https://rpubs.com/himanshu004/baseball_pitch_charts), with your reading and 'sperimenting, I'll bet we get there. Imagining the red & yellow above as pixelated, would the size of a pixel be about the cross-sectional height/width of a baseball?